# Moved files, but freed space still won't show

Tags: partition, kali-linux, disk-usage

I had a folder in my **Videos** */home/user/Videos* folder. It was over 17 Gb in size. Despite having seemingly freed up all this space, I'm unable to install a program (**Qt**). I keep getting the error that there isn't enough space.

What could be the problem?

> Kali GNU/Linux Rolling 64-bit

**UPDATE**

**df -h**

```
user@username:~$ sudo df -h
[sudo] password for username: 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           587M  8.8M  578M   2% /run
/dev/sda5        21G   13G  6.3G  67% /
tmpfs           2.9G   69M  2.8G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda8       1.3G  4.0M  1.2G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda6       7.0G  3.8G  2.8G  58% /var
/dev/sda9        78G  3.8G   71G   6% /home
tmpfs           587M   20K  587M   1% /run/user/132
tmpfs           587M   52K  587M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda1       151G  107G   45G  71% /media/username/63CA6D5A72F6F4CF
/dev/sda3       101G  100G  996M 100% /media/username/08BDB5EF06C52B43
/dev/sda4       101G   86G   16G  85% /media/username/5431214957EBF5D7
user@username:~$
```

Comment: Please give us your `df -h` output.

Comment: Just did an update with that @phk

Comment: Where/how are you trying to install? And what is the exact error message? It may be complaining about *any* file system. Freeing space in `/home` might not have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

If the install is using temporary disk space during setup, you have just 1.2 GB free in /tmp; that generally should be enough for smaller programs, but you could try

```
export TMP=/var/tmp
export TEMP=/var/tmp
```

and try the install again; you have 2.8 GB free there.  The install for Qt *should* check for disk space before running but it may not.  Where is it going to install?  in /usr/local/bin/?  That would end up in / where you just have 6.3 GB free.

Comment: maybe better to set `TMP=/var/tmp` ?

Comment: Yes, silly me.  Fixed.